# How to load some data from a Database on the first request but prevent other calls (at the same time) from doing it also in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization

I have a class which is registered with my Dependency Injection as a SINGLETON - so only one instance / the same instance of this class is injected into my MVC Controller.

In this class, I have a single method that does this:

- Load data from file/database (into RAM) on the VERY FIRST CALL to this method only. e.g. names of all the countries, or all the people in a movie, etc. whatever.
- Now do some really simple text query against this collection of data in RAM.

So the main point here is that I need to only load the data once. Here's my code btw..

```
public string Foo(ISession dbSession)
{
    LoadDataFromFileOrDbOrWherever();

    return GetAnswer(_data);
}
```

You get the idea. The main point of this is that the METHOD has to provide the current database session. This is what kills me :( I was thinking of using `Lazy<IList<MyData>>` and doing this in the constructor ... but I need the ISession to be passed into the constructor, which I actually don't have yet.

So what is the common pattern people do here, for getting some data on the first call only, remembering that .. and then referencing that, from now on.

If two or three calls are made at the same time, I'm expecting the 2nd/3rd/etc call to BLOCK/WAIT until the first call completes the data load process.

Initially I thought of Double-Checked locking ... but that's a sorta anti-pattern these days now that .NET has the nice `Lazy<T>` class.

Any ideas, kind folks?

Comment: Well this sound like a perfect place to use Task and async. have a InitAsync and all the other operations wait for it to be done.

Comment: I remember the creator of [Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache) talking about a similar problem. Found the [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7WnQhwBwqA)

Answer (score 1):

Your could use [LazyCache](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LazyCache/) which will execute your wished method once and will give you the cached result whenever you call it again.

```
using LazyCache;

IAppCache cache = new CachingService();
return await cache.GetOrAddAsync<ILoadChartStorageInformation[]>
(key, (Func<Task<ILoadChartStorageInformation[]>>) (async () =>
{
    return await someFunction();
}
```

Look at the LazyCache documentation to get a more detailed documentation:
https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache